# Android NavigationDrawer Automatically opens

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, navigation-drawer

I implemented the material navigation drawer with navigation view, in a fragment (Not a Activity). It works fine, but when i am coming back from anther fragment drawer automatically opens:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/bg_actionbar"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_slide_menu" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my main fragment implementation:

```
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, mToolBar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }
                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }
                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0); // this disables the animation
            }
        };
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        drawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
            actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
            // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        }
```

Code for calling new fragment.

```
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener = new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_help:
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setFragment(new HelpFragment(), HelpFragment.getTAG());
                    return true;
                default:
                    return true;

            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: show your code for drawer item selection and navigation to new fragment

Comment: please check i update the code

Comment: It should not happend, can you please show if you have overriden `onResume` , `onStart`?

Comment: no, navigation drawer implement on fragment onCreateView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement NavigationDrawer in Main Activity instead of a fragment,

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, mToolBar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0); // this disables the animation
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        List<String> menuItemResList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items));
        ArrayList<String> menuItemResArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(menuItemResList);

        final NavigationRecyclerAdapter navigationRecyclerAdapter = new NavigationRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, menuItemResArrayList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(navigationRecyclerAdapter);
```